# Once inserted, data in Firebase is automatically disappearing for some unknown reason

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, storing-data

I made another post to explain better, ok? :)

This video shows exactly what I mean:
The video is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCg00fe-_xs

Firebase normally stores data. After the 6th second of the video, trying to enter new data, the data stays about a second in Firebase, but automatically then it disappears.

I try to input the data into Firebase two more times in this video, but the data always automatically disappears afterwards.

You can see that the other datas that are stored in Firebase does NOT disappear. But the data of this code is automatically disappearing for some reason as shown in the video. Please what can I do to fix it?

Code:

```
button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String raça = spinner_raca.getSelectedItem().toString();
                final String regiaoDoEstado = spinner_regiaoDoEstado.getSelectedItem().toString();
                final String estado = spinner_estado.getSelectedItem().toString();
 
                Intent receiverIntent = getIntent();
                Bundle bundleRecebedor = receiverIntent.getExtras();
                String nomecompleto = bundleRecebedor.getString("nomecompleto");
                String email = bundleRecebedor.getString("email");
                String doencasPreExistentes = bundleRecebedor.getString("doencasPreExistentes");
                String dataDeNascimento = bundleRecebedor.getString("dataDeNascimento");
                String genero = bundleRecebedor.getString("genero");
                String identificadorEmHash = bundleRecebedor.getString("identificadorEmHash");
                String telefone = receiverIntent.getStringExtra("telefone");

                reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child(identificadorEmHash);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), identificadorEmHash, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(identificadorEmHash.equals(null)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The identifier does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuarios").child(identificadorEmHash);
                            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The identifier does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {

                                HashMap<String, String> sendDataToDataBase = new HashMap<>();
                                    sendDataToDataBase.put("Nome Completo", nomecompleto);
                                    sendDataToDataBase.put("E-mail", email);
                                    sendDataToDataBase.put("Identificador em Hash", identificadorEmHash);
                                    sendDataToDataBase.put("Telefone", telefone);
                                    sendDataToDataBase.put("Doenças Pré Existentes", doencasPreExistentes);
                                    sendDataToDataBase.put("Data de Nascimento", dataDeNascimento);
                                    sendDataToDataBase.put("Gênero", genero);
                 // When I am going to send the following data to Firebase, the problem of the video happens.
                                    sendDataToDataBase.put("Região do Estado em que mora", regiaoDoEstado);
                                    sendDataToDataBase.put("Raça", raça);
                                    sendDataToDataBase.put("Estado do Brasil em que mora", estado);

                                try {
                                    raiz.child(identificadorEmHash).setValue(sendDataToDataBase);

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.getMessage();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Please, can someone help me to fix this bug?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase doesn't automatically delete data, so if you see the data show up in the console it was written there by a client/API call, and allowed by your security rules. If the data subsequently gets updates or removed again, there is another client/API call that does so.

I recommend checking for realtime listeners in your code, that may be responding to your first write by updating (and accidentally reverting) that operation. It is also quite common to have a server-side script that is doing this.

---

Update: one thing you can try is to [use `updateChildren`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) instead of `setValue` in all places such as this one:

```
raiz.child(identificadorEmHash).updateChildren(sendDataToDataBase)
```

Comment: Thank you very much again, Frank van Puffelen. I will check this.

Comment: Please, if anyone has another good idea of ​​what might be going wrong, please, write.

Comment: @Carl, you should check any user sign up flows in your app or on any backends. This looks like you've created a user, created their user data and then asked for more details from the user. Once you write the new data, the listener you set up from before is retriggering and putting the data back to what it was when the user first signed up.

Comment: Good point Sam. @Carl: I also added another hint on what to try, but in the end this will likely require you to do local debugging of your app.